# Manipulating python lists. (accessing specific elements)

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix, indexing

I am a filling a list (named foo) in this way:

```
foo = []

for index, elem in enumerate(alpha):
    if elem>0.00001:
        print (index,elem)
        foo.append([elem, myarray[index]])
```

Now, lets see what `foo[0]` contains:

```
output: [14601132722.531921, array([ 0.6135447, -0.874145 , -1.       ])
```

I really want to be able to access somehow every single of these values for further processing. So far I have got every single possible error this python language can produce.

Or better, to store these values in a normal `Nx4` matrix or array whatever they call it in python.

Comment: Are you trying to set this up like a dictionary? `14601132722.531921` as the key and the `array([ 0.6135447, -0.874145 , -1.       ]` as the value? And then accessing each of the values? Also what is alpha?

Comment: What is `myarray`?  What is `alpha`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the output you are getting, I am guessing `myarray` is actually a 2-dimensional numpy array of shape `Nx3` .

And as you say -

> Or better, to store these values in a **normal Nx4 matrix or array**

If that is the case, and you want crap to simply be a list of lists with each sublist having `4` elements. You can create a temporary list in the inner loop and extend that with `myarray[index]` , to make it 4 elements, and then append it to `crap`. Example -

```
for index, elem in enumerate(alpha):
    if elem>0.00001:
        print (index,elem)
        temp = [elem]
        temp.extend(myarray[index])
        crap.append(temp)
```

Comment: That was pretty cool. Also, I was able to convert it into a numpy array. Thank you.